# Canvas clears on parent element attribute change

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I create a canvas on the fly from a video. This works great and the canvas is correct and shall never be changed. So what I do I wrap the canvas in 2 divs. Now I change any attribute, even when I call `element.setAttribute('test','')`, via js on one of the 3 elements and the canvas clears.

I have sadly no clue why this is happening. I only want to set the positioning of the direct canvas parent, and its parent shall toggle between `display: none` and `display: block`

Any idea why this is happening and how I can prevent it?

[EDIT] I found the problem:

To append the canvas at the correct position I changed

```
container.innerHTML = ''
container.appendChild(canvas)
```

to

```
container.innerHTML = canvas.outerHTML
```

The later is initially fine, however when I change something on any attribute of the canvas, the container or parent the canvas content clears.

Why is this? Shouldn't the code do the same thing?

Tested in Firefox, Chrome & Chromium

Comment: what if you have a different element other than `canvas` ... does that disappear too?

Comment: What does disappeared mean? Not visible, not in dom or cleared? Does it also happen in firefox?

Comment: We need a [MCVE] here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the attribute that causes the problem, but the canvas you create by doing

```
container.innerHTML = canvas.outerHTML
```

is not the same `canvas` anymore, but an entirely new canvas element, which doesn't have any context initialized, and which will be fully transparent.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const output = document.getElementById('output');

output.append( canvas );
console.log(
  'same canvas with append?',
  document.querySelector('#output>canvas') === canvas
); // true

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = canvas.outerHTML;
console.log(
  'same canvas with innerHTML?',
  document.querySelector('#output>canvas') === canvas
); // false
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

So if you want to keep the drawings of your canvas, you need to keep that same element in the DOM, and for this you need to append it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This helped me understand the issue at hand better